# Spring 4 mvc login intercepting

Tags: spring, security, model-view-controller, interceptor

I am new at Spring mvc. I am working on a webpage on which users will be able to log in after they have registered and activated themselves.
I sucessfully implemented the Login part, it works fine.
I would like to check if the user has already activated his/her accout via email before the login process launches. Is it possible?
I have tried to solve it with a Login interceptor, but it seems the default "/j_spring_security_check" can not be intercepted. Except this link the interceptor works with all of the url-s.
Is it possible to intercept this default link?

My spring-security.xml

```
...
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />  
    <form-login login-page="/login" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />  
    <!--enable csrf protection-->
    <csrf />
</http>

<authentication-manager>  
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="loginService" />  
</authentication-manager>
```

LoginService

```
@Service("loginService")  
public class LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {  
//It is a regular UserDetailsService nothing extra stuff and works fine
...
}
```

Login.jsp

```
....
<div id="login-box">
    <span  style="color: red">${message}</span>   
    <c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" var="loginUrl"/>
    <form name='f' action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
        <p>
            <label for="username">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>  
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>  
        </p>
        <input type="hidden"                        
            name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
    </form>
</div>
...
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
...
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/j_spring_security_check"/>
        <bean id="logininterceptor" class="org.psi.controller.LoginInterCeptor"></bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
...
```

LoginInterceptor

```
public class LoginInterCeptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
@Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        //Do some check
        System.out.println("some check");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any other possible solution are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would accomplish this by using either the `locked` or `enabled` property on the `UserDetails` object and let Spring handle the rest rather than trying to intercept the request.  When the user confirms their email via the link you send them, flip the flag in the database to indicate the the user is either enabled or not locked.

Alternatively, if you really want to go the intercept route, what I might do is have the login form point to something other than `j_spring_security_check`, intercept whatever that is, and then (if desired) forward the request to `j_spring_security_check`.  I'm not sure if you can actually override that url.

Comment: It is possible to change the  j_spring_security_check link.
I tried it but when the forwarding happens, I get the following exception:
    No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/PsiWeb/j_spring_security_check] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

I also tried the locked enabled flags, but if one of them is false I got the invalid username or password message on the login page.
However it worths reading after, maybe I am just missing something.

Comment: I read after the locked, enabled flags. It is a good solution for my issue. I found this page: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-limit-login-attempts-example/ followed the steps and it works fine.